# Instance <User at xxxx> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I first request is right, But when I second request is wrong. I know the reason get this result is session object expired. But I don't know why? The flowing is my test script.
Detail:
In my actual project, I set a global variable current_user to save the current user, and then add some cache-related attributes to this global variable. The cache-related attributes are actually an object, which is called in the method of the object Pass in the ginseng.

```
import datetime
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Integer, Column, DateTime, Integer, String, func, VARCHAR

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config[
    "SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"
] = "mysql+mysqlconnector://root:123456@127.0.0.1:3306/pool"
# app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app) 
# In my project I set global var to solve memory leak 
current_user = {}


def get_cache(user):
    def inner():
        class hello:
            def get_user_name(self):
                # if user not in db.session:
                #     print("user 已经过期了")
                #     session_user = db.session.merge(user)
                # else:
                #     session_user = user
                # return "%s" % (session_user.username)
                return "%s" % (user.username)

        return hello()

    return inner()


def get_current_user(ticker):
    user = current_user.get(ticker)
    if user:
        return user
    user = User.query.first()
    current_user[ticker] = user
    user.cache = get_cache(user)
    return user


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "user"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column(String(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    mobile = Column(String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    is_admin = Column(Integer, default=0)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    level = Column(Integer, default=1)
    remark = Column(String(100), nullable=False)


@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    db.session.rollback()
    db.session.remove()
    return response


@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    user = get_current_user("ltc")
    print(user.username, "这个")
    print(user.cache.get_user_name())
    return "hello world"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=5000)
```

My environment:

```
Flask==1.0.2  
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2
```

Comment: if there isn't a specific thing which you want to use. This is already handled by the 'flask_login' module. Simply you can use it as : from flask_login import current_user, login_user and setup other configurations. You can check the description in URL.(https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-v-user-logins).

Comment: This is not login problem. I only set the variable name is current_user. In my project, this variable is not able to login.